# How to create a linq lambda join query that pulls results even though there null results?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, lambda

I have this join query that pulls all school programs and products that is in a person's shopping cart:

```
//this pulls all items the user purchased
var poop = Context.Query<Cart>().Where(x => x.UserId == currentUserId && x.Status == "Archived")
    .Select(
        p => new
        {
            p.ItemId,
            p.TypeId,
            p.PurchaseDate
        })
//This get the media type name of the cart items
    .Join(
        Context.Query<MediaType>(),
        t => new {t.TypeId},
        m => new {TypeId = m.Id},
        (t, m) => new
        {
            t.ItemId,
            t.TypeId,
            t.PurchaseDate,
            m.TypeName
        }).OrderBy(d => d.PurchaseDate)
//Now i need specifics of the items like name, sku, etc. StartDate will be null for items that are products, but contains DateTime for items that are programs.
    .Join(
        Context.Query<ProgramProductView>(),
        e => new {e.ItemId, e.TypeId},
        prog => new {ItemId = prog.Id, prog.TypeId},
        (e, prog) => new
        {
            e.ItemId,
            e.TypeId,
            e.PurchaseDate,
            e.TypeName,
            prog.FullName,
            prog.StartDate,
            prog.Sku,
            prog.Closed
        }).OrderBy(d => d.PurchaseDate);
```

So right there is where it crashes because prog.StartDate is null for products. I get *SQL is not available*  error.

Is there a way to have the join allow null-able fields? I am only using lambda because it's easier to read and clean.

Comment: Try `(DateTime?)prog.StartDate`

Comment: *facepalm.... wow that was simple. thanks. can you make that the answer?

Comment: Just put this into the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you just need to use `Nullable<>` property for you anonymous class in your last `Join`:

```
.Join(
    Context.Query<ProgramProductView>(),
    e => new {e.ItemId, e.TypeId},
    prog => new {ItemId = prog.Id, prog.TypeId},
    (e, prog) =>
        new
        {
            ...
            (DateTime?)prog.StartDate,
            ...
         }).OrderBy(d => d.PurchaseDate);
```

Hope it will help.